# Как вытащить HTML код у UserControl *.ascx?

Tags: asp.net, .net

Control рендерится, если состоит из не серверных контролов, а из простых HTML тегов к примеру `<button></button>`, а если  `<asp:button/>`, то нет...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё разобрался, просто `<asp:button/>` нужна `<asp:form runat="server"/>` форма, так как `<asp:button/>` является **submit** элементом а при render
`<asp:form runat="server"> <asp:button/> </asp:form>` генерится

```
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/...PGU=" />
</div>
<button></button>
```

получается что при submit нужна информация о кантролах хронящаяся в __VIEWSTATE.
но если так сделать то всёравно не срендерится так как стаит защита для страницы Page [EnableEventValidation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.ui.page.enableeventvalidation.aspx) = true по умолчанию, если же поставить значение в false то страница срендерит но в MSDN написано что не стоит этого делать.
Ну если использовать другие **asp:controls** то рендерится без проблем!!!

Comment: учтите, что __VIEWSTATE генерится одна на страницу, если есть хотя бы один Web-контрол. Валидация контролов происходит, если на странице созданы валидаторы.

Answer (score 0):

Я рекомендую Вам создавать Web-страницы не с нуля, а с использованием шаблонов Visual Studio.